# Embedding countable ordinals into closed subsets of stationary subsets of $\omega_1$

Tags: set-theory

I am trying to solve exercise 8.5 from Jech's *Set Theory* (2003).

**I know that this problem has already an answer on this website, but I do not ask for a solution. Rather, I would like to know whether my attempted solution is correct.**

***If it is not, please do not simply tell me the answer, but suggest to me where I go wrong, so I can figure it out myself.***

**Exercise.**
For any stationary $S \subseteq \omega_1$ and any $\alpha < \omega_1$ there exists a closed $A \subseteq S$ such that $\textrm{otyp} (A) = \alpha$.

*Proof (?):*
By induction. The induction hypothesis is that
$$
  \forall \textrm{ stationary}\: S \subseteq \omega_1 \ldotp \forall \:\xi < \alpha \ldotp \exists \textrm{ closed}\:A_\xi \textrm{ such  that} \textit{ otyp} ( A_\xi) = \xi.
  $$
The case where $\alpha = \xi +1$ is trivial, since  by $S$ being stationary there exists an $\nu \in S$ greater than all elements of $A_\xi$. But then $A_\xi\,  \cup \,\{\nu\} \subseteq S$ is the required closed set.

Thus assume that $\alpha \in \textrm{Lim} \cap \omega_1$. Since $\alpha < \omega_1$, we have cf($\alpha$)$\:= \omega$. Let $\langle \alpha_n : n<\omega \rangle$ be an $\omega$-sequence beginning with $\alpha_0 = 0$ and limit $\alpha$. Let $
A_{0} = \emptyset$, and let $A_{n+1}$ be a closed $\subseteq S$ such that $\textit{otyp} (A_{n+1}) = \alpha_{n+1}$, and such that any $\xi \in A_{n+1}$ is larger than any $\nu \in A_{n}$ (the induction hypothesis and the stationarity of $S$ ensure the existence of such $A_{n+1}\subseteq S$ with arbitrarily large least elements).

Now let $A'_{0} := \emptyset$, and let

$
A'_{n+1} := A_{n+1} - \{\nu = \textit{enum}_{A_{n+1}}(\xi)\: : \:  \xi > \alpha_{n-1} \: \textrm{ or } \: \alpha_{n} > \xi\}.
$

(Note that, using the von Neumann ordinals, $\alpha_{0-1} = \alpha_{0} = 0$.) We claim that $A := \bigcup\limits_{n=0}^{\omega} A'_{n}$ is the required closed subset of $S$ with $\textit{otyp}\,(A) = \alpha$. The $A'_n$ correspond to $\omega$-many pairwise disjoint "slices" of a set of order-type $\alpha$ embedded into $S$. By construction, each $A'_n$ is closed (in particular, each $A'_n$ contains its own supremum), and thus their union is also closed.

*For the sake of clarity: the intuitive idea underlying this proof is that we first construct an $\omega$-sequence of subsets of S whose increasing ordertypes approximate $\alpha$, and then 'cut off' open beginning and ending segments of each of them in such a way to get an $\omega$-sequence of closed sets whose union has ordertype $\alpha$.*

*Edit 1:* This is cannot be correct. I am not properly dealing with the difficult case, namely when, by the induction hypothesis, we have open $\alpha$-sequences in $S$ but need to find an $\alpha$-sequence $\langle \alpha_\xi : \xi<\alpha \rangle$ such that $\lambda =$ lim$_{\xi \rightarrow \alpha}\alpha_\xi \in S$.

Comment: The exercise is incorrect. E.g. if $S=\omega_1$ and $\alpha=\omega.$ Any non-empty countable $closed$ $A\subset \omega_1$ has a largest member so $ot(A)\ne \omega.$ Perhaps if we assume that $(\omega_1 \setminus S)\cap Lim$  is unbounded, and if we replace "closed" with "closed in the subspace $S$" but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Wait, did I make a mistake in stating the problem. Is the *length* of a well-ordered sequence not necessarily the same as its *ordertype*? Is $length(\langle\0,1,2,3, ...\rangle$ equal to of $length(\langle 0,1,2,3, ..., \omega\rangle)$? No, right? I seem to recall that the problem was stated with length instead of ordertype, but I'm under the impression that these are the same in the case of ordinal sequences.

Comment: The order-type $ot(A)$ is the ordinal that $A$ is order-isomorphic to. I am not familiar with "length" in this context.